# How do I multiply uint with ufixed?

Tags: solidity

in my contract I need to do some calculations to convert some ERC20 tokens value to WEI and I need to do something like:

```
tokenValueWei(uint) = tokenValue(uint) * multiplier(ufixed)
```

eg. 100000012 (some token fractions) * 0.0013233 (multiplier) = 132330 (WEI rounded)

while the multiplier is being supplied to the contract by the contract manager.
Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ufixed` is not supported yet in Solidity.

The trick that you always can apply is: scale the numbers by the precision that you need.

For instance, if you need precision 18: you can pass the multiplier as `uint` as `multiplier*(10**18)`. At the end you simply divide the result by `10**18` and everything is fine.